# Mock the onCreate of an activity when initialized with Espresso ActivityTestRule without using Dagger

Tags: java, android, dagger, android-espresso

I try to initialize my activity with espresso and mock the onCreate but did not find a good solution without adding Dagger to my project:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MyActivity.class);
```

I tried also to create a custom rule but this did not help since I don't have access to mock the activity just right before it is createa...
Only after the creation, but the onCreate at that time is already called.

```
public class MyCustomRule<A extends MyActivity> extends ActivityTestRule<A> { ....
  @Override
  protected void beforeActivityLaunched(){super.beforeActivityLaunched();}
  @Override
  protected Intent getActivityIntent() {...}
  @Override
  protected void afterActivityLaunched() {...}
  @Override
  protected void afterActivityFinished() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the problem I had, by using the [SingleActivityFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/intercepting/SingleActivityFactory.html):

```
private SingleActivityFactory<MyActivity> injectedFactory = new SingleActivityFactory<MyActivity>(MyActivity.class) {
 @Override
 protected MyActivity create(Intent intent) {
    MyActivity activity = new MockMyActivity();
    return activity;
 }
};
```

And use this to create the Rule

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(injectedFactory, false, true);
```

Where your MockMyActivity.class would look something like this:

```
public class MockMyActivity extends MyActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // you can add some of your logic here
    }

    @Override
    protected MyFragment findOrCreateViewFragment() {
      MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contentFrame);
      if (myFragment == null) {
         //spy-mock your fragment
         myFragment = spy(new MyFragment());
         // ex do not load data from the web service
         doNothing().when(myFragment).callLoadMyService();

        ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity(getSupportFragmentManager(), myFragment, R.id.contentFrame);
      }
      return myFragment;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for a way to launch a mocked Activity that was obviously not declared in the app manifest and yours is the only way to do so (so it seem). I wonder why you did not get much more upvotes.